# Type of neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

I have a data with next structure for example.

```
no,2,0,8,2
no,1,1,16,2
yes,1,0,4,1
no,0,1,11,2
no,2,1,3,1
no,2,1,11,2
no,2,1,1,0
no,0,0,20,2
yes,1,0,6,0
yes,0,1,11,1
no,1,1,22,2
yes,1,0,24,0
yes,1,0,10,0
```

I want create a model, which selects a best values for parameters, when we have a first parameter equal "yes".

What type of model will be better for these data?

Comment: Is it possible to say, that by the value of the first column, you want to get four others ?

Comment: Can you please tell why you chosen among tags prediction?